# Does man have a directory? And is it updated ever?

Tags: manpage

I would like to know if `man` has a directory where it stores all the man pages and if it updates itself or it is updated and upgraded through `apt update` and `apt upgrade`? Anyone have any useful insight?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/318555/where-are-man-pages-stored-in-ubuntu

Comment: apt update only updates the package indexes as far as I’m aware, apt upgrade is what actually upgrades programs

Comment: Could you please answer the second part of the question also?

Comment: @NerdOfCode to address second part of your question, see my answer ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `man` has a directory. Whenever `apt` updates or installs a package, it will also add the new or updated versions of the manuals to the manpages directory.

As such, there are very few cases where a manpage will update outside of `apt` triggering that update as part of an automatic install.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

When you install a package, `dpkg` also extract package's manual pages in the expected directories, after that it's going to trigger a `mandb` update, then `mandb` updates the manual page caches.

You can run it manually if you like `sudo mandb`, `mandb`.

To find about paths which "mandb" uses to index manuals you can use `manpath` command and to find an specific man page use `-w` switch from `man` command like: `man -w man`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `man` has a directory concerning man pages: `/usr/share/man`.

A more detailed explanation can be found [here](https://superuser.com/questions/318555/where-are-man-pages-stored-in-ubuntu).

Also, aptitude does update man pages. Just run `sudo apt-get install wine` and you will notice that there are man pages explaining the inner workings of `wine`.

In addition, this doesn't really concern ubuntu as generally as it should; it alludes more towards system administration. As such, this question should be migrated to super user, where it will promptly get a 'duplicate'. A simple google search could have saved you time. Have a [look](https://www.google.ch/search?q=linux+man+pages+location&oq=linux+man+pages+location&aqs=chrome..69i57.3199j0j1&client=ubuntu&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).